# what type of encode is that

Tags: encoding, utf-8, decode, encode

I have a dump file with a lot of lines like this:

```
$0414$0436$0435$0434$0430$0439
$05DE$05E1$05D3$05E8_$05D4$05D2$0027$05D3$05D9$05D9
```

I assume the strings above do means "Джедаи" (russian) and "מסדר_הג'דיי" (hebrew).

How can I decode these strings ?
Which encode is that ?

Comment: probably hex values, but we're not cryptographers/decoders...

Comment: I think it's `UTF-32`. Check here: http://encoder.mattiasgeniar.be/index.php.

Comment: @Akar: It is UTF-16, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file contains UTF-16 code units formatted as 16bit hex strings, each beginning with `$`.  Except for the `_` ASCII character (U+005F) in `מסדר_הג'דיי`, which has been written to the file as-is instead of being hex encoded.  Oddly, the `'` ASCII character (U+0027) in `מסדר_הג'דיי` has been hex encoded.

To decode this, you would read the file one character at a time.  When you detect a `$` character, skip it and hex-decode the next 4 characters into a 16bit value, otherwise treat the character as-is as a 16bit value.  Build up a string of these 16bit values, and you will have a UTF-16 encoded string.